# Compute matrix inverse at scale separated orders

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics, numerical-calculus

Consider a square $N$ invertible matrix $M$ where $N=100...1000$. The question was to compute the numerical value of the inverse of the matrix $M$. The issue was, the entry of $M$ ranged at large scale separated orders, between $10^{-200}$ to $10^{200}$, so when terms multiply together $5.5\times 10^{-200}+1.5\times (10^{-200})^2$ were essentially zero or infinity with respect to each other. Thus, the usual methods such as the Gaussian elimination will not return an actual inverse matrix, but rather a matrix with large scale separated remainders, i.e.

$$\text{max entry}(\text{Gaussian Elimination Inverse}(M)M)=1.6\times 10^{150}$$

What's the best way to compute the matrix inverse at scale separated orders?

Comment: Apply sparse reordering algorithms to concentrate large entries close to the diagonal (or in an arrow shape). Use a stable decomposition like QR or SVD instead of Gaussian elimination (even in its pivoted version the size of the numbers in intermediate may blow up).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. Could you explain more about the sparse reordering algorithms, please? I've been googling and reading for an hour but didn't get much. First, most of the entry of the matrix $M$ should not be zeros. Also, I don't quite understand how the "bandwidth minimization" will be related to this question. The QR decomposition might run into the similar issues because of the Gram–Schmidt process. SVD might be useful, but I'm a bit confused of how to find the eigenvalue of this matrix, the scale separation made the computation of determinant complicated, before eigenvalues.

Comment: Your main problem with Gauß is that the intermediary entries can grow quite fast. Reducing them down to the magnitude of the result involves catastrophic cancellation. By "sparse reordering" I mean to apply something like the maximum matching algorithm to the magnitude levels of the matrix entries and arrange the matching on the diagonal. This is some kind of global pivoting that hopefully reduces the depth of cancellation chains when applying Gauß. That's just an idea for heuristics, an eventual answer will be more precise or otherwise refute this idea.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think I just found something crazier. I posted another question referenced and related to this one since it's very different and somewhat analytic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668799/the-matrix-inverse-of-beginpmatrix-a-11-1010-a-12-1030-newline-a

Comment: A related post about the block inversion algorithm, it's not yet clear if it would work: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670440/does-block-inversion-algorithms-improve-numerical-stability